# How to use XML as content on DD4T 2 Java version

Tags: dd4t, java

I'm implementing DD4T 2 java version.
This version of DD4T uses JSON as published content by default, but I want to use XML instead of JSON, because of weird behaviour of component's keyword field. I posted about the "weird behaviour".

[DD4T default TBB add unnecessary keyword field values to JSON](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12585/dd4t-default-tbb-add-unnecessary-keyword-field-values-to-json)

By default, DD4T 2 uses "JsonDataBinder". But I couldn't find any class that bind XML to DD4T object, something like "XmlDataBinder". Is creating a new class that bind XML by myself required?

Regards,

Comment: A bit late - I'm just reading this now, but indeed - you'll need to write an XMLDataBinder yourself. We simply did't have the time. Given the answer in the other question - this is now fixed anyway. :)